# How do I compose a single reducer to handle different actions in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple counter app, that increments, decrements, and maintains a total count of all clicks. [Codesandbox - vanilla](https://codesandbox.io/s/o53onw6729). I am trying to do the same thing in Redux, [Codesandbox - Redux][1]. I think the problem is how I am composing the total reducer.

actions.js

```
export const incrementNum = () => ({
  type: constants.TOTAL,
  type: constants.INCREMENT
});

export const decrementNum = () => ({
  type: constants.TOTAL,
  type: constants.DECREMENT
});

export const total = () => ({
  type: constants.TOTAL
});
```

reducers.js

```
const decreasedNum = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.DECREMENT:
      console.log("decrement was dispatched to decremnt reducer");
      console.log(state, action);
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// takes a user click event and returns an action to send
// to other components
const increasedNum = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.INCREMENT:
      console.log("increment was dispatched to incremnet reducer", state);
      console.log(state, action);
      return state + 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const totalNum = (state = 0, action) => {
  let count = { num: 0, inc: 0, dec: 0 };
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.INCREMENT:
      console.log("increment was dispatched to incremnet reducer ++++", state);
      //count.num = state +1;
      return state + 1;
    case constants.DECREMENT:
      console.log("decrement was dispatched to decremnt reducer ----");
      return state - 1;
    case constants.TOTAL:
      console.log("total is fired", state);
      count.num = state + 1;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

container component

```
class CounterContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let number = this.props.totalNum;
    number = Math.abs(this.props.totalNum) + 1;
    console.log(number, this.props.totalNum, "component is getting props");
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.totalNum}</h1>
        <div className="clicks">{this.props.totalNum}</div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <Decrement
            decrementNum={this.props.decrementNum}
            totalNum={this.props.total}
          />
          <Increment
            incrementNum={this.props.incrementNum}
            totalNum={this.props.total}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { totalNum: state.totalNum };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ incrementNum, decrementNum, total }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CounterContainer);
```

My original intention was to have both increment and decrement reducers passed to total, use Math.abs on decrement and add them together. Before I keep throwing crap at the wall I want to understand where I went wrong and what is the best pattern for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: My decrement and increment components have the onClick{props.decrementNum();
        props.totalNum();} for example. I this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you have multiple types the payload you are dispatching. Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

actions.js:

```js
export const incrementNum = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: constants.TOTAL})
    dispatch({type: constants.INCREMENT})
  }
};

export const decrementNum = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: constants.TOTAL})
    dispatch({type: constants.DECREMENT})
  }
}

export const total = () => ({
  type: constants.TOTAL
});
```

After looking at the sandbox I see the result you are going for... So I would setup the reducers to go with the above actions like so:

reducer.js

```js
export default handleActions({
  [constants.INCREMENT]: (state) => ({...state, inc: (state.inc+1)}),
  [constants.DECREMENT]: (state) => ({...state, dec: (state.dec+1)}),
  [constants.TOTAL]: (state) => ({...state, total: (state.total+1)})
}, {total: 0, inc: 0, dec: 0})
```

Comment: So when passing a type to the reducer, it's best to only pass one? I thought that the payload was another separate property that is passed to the action and then sent to the reducer. As for what you have, we can dispatch multiple types as long as they are wrapped in a single dispatch?

Comment: Yes, the payload can be in the action you dispatch. I am a little confused by your reducers. Each reducer is handling all your types. You should maybe think about reworking those so you have a reducer that handles each type.

Comment: It's a mess, indeed. What I was trying to do in totalNum reducer is to take the result of decrement and increment and pass it into a variable and combine the results.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax. I am exporting one object composed of reducers. Then in the <Increment />, <Decrement /> components I pass {props.handleActions} or {props.handleActions()} ?

Comment: handleActions is for your reducer. You still pass in your action functions to your components (like you are). Then when you execute the action (incrementNum) then it will dispatch the constants.INCREMENT type that will be handled in your reducer.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused about where put this. Which reducer, totalNum? I'm only allowed one default export and I already export my combineReducers(increasedNum, decreasedNum, totalNum).

Answer (score 0):

This should really all be handled by the same reducer, I think you are over complicating it a little bit.

```
const initialState = {
  actionsHandled: 0,
  total: 0,
};

const increment = {
  type: 'INCREMENT',
};

const decrement = {
  type: 'DECREMENT',
};

const countReducer = (state = initialState, { type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return {
        actionsHandled: state.actionsHandled + 1,
        total: state.total + 1,
      };
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return {
        actionsHandled: state.actionsHandled + 1,
        total: state.total - 1,
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
        actionsHandled: state.actionsHandled + 1,
      };
  }
};
```

This way you track the number of actions you've handled/how many times it has been called, but then also allow for the inc/dec to work.  You can modify multiple parts of the state in a reducer, you don't need a reducer per piece of data.